# dependency-injector: How to provide fallbacks for configuration values?

Tags: python, dependency-injection

I’m in the process of introducing dependency-injector to some old projects. In one of them I have a config value that has a fallback to another value and a default value. Essentially I’m looking for an equivalent of:

```py
value = config.get("value", config.get("fallback", "default"))
```

I’m especially interested in how to pass such a value to a service defined in a `provider.DeclarativeContainer`.

While [the docs](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/) provide many examples on how to [add configuration from different sources](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/providers/configuration.html) I couldn’t find a lot about accessing config values. I also looked at the docstrings of the methods of `provider.Configuration()`  but without success.

Answer (score 0):

I have now found a solution that I think is good enough. It is based on the config provider returning `None` for config keys that are not required.

```py
from dependency_injector import containers, providers

def first_not_none(*args):
    return next((a for a in args if a is not None), None)

def fallback(*args):
    return providers.Callable(first_not_none, *args)


class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):

    config = providers.Configuration()
    example = providers.Factory(
        lambda x: x,
        fallback(config.value, config.fallback, "default"),
    )

# Test scenarios
container = Container()
assert container.example() == "default"

container = Container()
container.config.from_dict({"fallback": "fallback"})
assert container.example() == "fallback"

container = Container()
container.config.from_dict({"value": "value"})
assert container.example() == "value"
```